# Issue with Google calendar ICS file import

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I'm trying to create a program which help me to import programmatically my school event. The output file (calendarXXXXX...ics) looks like this:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:xxx
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20171023T140000Z
DTEND:20171023T160000Z
UID:xxx
CREATED:20171017T165457Z
DESCRIPTION:xxx
LOCATION:xxx
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:xxx
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20171025T090000Z
DTEND:20171025T130000Z
UID:xxx
CREATED:20171017T165457Z
DESCRIPTION:xxx
LOCATION:xxx
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:xxx
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

When I try to import this file in Google Calendar it told me that it had elaborated all Y events, but only one was imported. Someone can help me with some suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A event UID is important - it's a unique identifier.  If you used xxx for all of them, google probably treated it all as relating the same event.

Try validating your ics files.  The validators are not perfect but they help.
https://icalendar.org/validator.html  and http://severinghaus.org/projects/icv/ say missing DTSTAMPs

http://ical-validator.herokuapp.com/ says:
! CRLF should be used for newlines
Related RFC 5545 section: 3.1
**! UID [xxx] encountered multiple times
Related RFC 5545 section: 3.8.4.7**